# The variables won't registered in the global context, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used to think that all the parameters and named functions not inside a function should be registered in the global context(in 'this' context), but the following code made me confused.

**Why the variable without keyword var could be registered in 'this' context whereas the others couldn't?**

```
g_var_1 = "I'm in the global context";
var g_var_2 = "I'm not in the global context";

function g_func() {
    console.log("why I'm not in the global context?");
}

(function() {
    console.log(this);          //do not see g_var_2 and g_func
})();

//test the global context variables
(function() {
    console.log(this.g_var_1);  //ok
    console.log(this.g_var_2);  //undefined
    console.log(g_var_1);       //ok
    console.log(g_var_2);       //ok
    this.g_func();              //Error
    g_func();                   //ok
})();
```

Comment: You should code in strict mode where there are no implicit globals and there are no accidental values for `this`. Both of those are horrible things that the original designers of Javascript did and they are trying like heck to get rid of it over time. Then a variable will only exist in the scope in which you declare it and any child scopes that can also see it. And, `this` will not have a value at all unless you explicitly cause it to  have a particular value. So, there will be no accidents that happen to work and no accidents that happen to cause trouble. Try running your code in strict mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just want to figure out how this works beneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, since this is tagged as node.js, you should realize that a node.js module which all code in node.js is contained within is actually inside a function itself.

Every node.js module is wrapped inside of something like this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    // Your module code actually lives in here
});
```

So, something you declare at the top scope in a node.js module is actually not at the top scope - it's inside a wrapper function.

Secondly, this question can only be addressed by discussing both strict mode and non-strict mode.  Since it appears that you could run your code, you must be running it in non-strict mode.  For that, you get the following rules:

1. Any non-declared variable you assign to becomes an implicit global.
2. Any plain function you call sets the `this` pointer to the global object.

So, now using those two rules, let's look at your results:

`g_var1` become a global.

`g_var2` is not a global.  It's explicitly declared in the module scope which as described above it not the top level.  It's inside a module function wrapper.

`g_func` is similarly not a global.  It's a module level function.

Then, when you do this:

```
(function() {
    console.log(this);          //do not see g_var_2 and g_func
})();
```

The value of `this` is set to the `global` object and you don't see `g_var_2` and `g_func` because as I said earlier, they are not globals, but have module scope.

Then, when you run this:

```
//test the global context variables
(function() {
    console.log(this.g_var_1);  //ok
    console.log(this.g_var_2);  //undefined
    console.log(g_var_1);       //ok
    console.log(g_var_2);       //ok
    this.g_func();              //Error
    g_func();                   //ok
})();
```

`this` is set to the global object.  `g_var_1` is a true global so `this.g_var_1` works.  Since `g_var_2` and `g_func` are not global symbols, neither of them can be referenced via `this`.

But, all of `g_var_1`, `g_var_2` and `g_func` are in a parent scope so you can reference them by themselves just fine.

---

Now, let's talk about how you should program in `strict` mode.  `strict` mode is the Javascript effort to rid the language of the horrible things it was born with that automatically made undeclared variables into globals and automatically set the value of `this` to the global object in plain functions.  Those two things lead to many, many accidental bugs where the code reports no errors, but does not do what you intended because of some slight typing mistake.

So, in `strict` mode, if you try to use a variable that you have not declared, you get an immediate error (the logic is that it's a problem that should be fixed).  And, inside a regular function the value of `this` is `undefined`.

So, in your scheme:

The assignment to `g_var_1` would immediately cause an error.  You'd have to declare it as either a global or a module variable in order to use it at all.  The other variables are declared so their scope stays the same.

Inside of this:

```
(function() {
    console.log(this);
})();
```

The value of `this` would be `undefined`.  Then, in here:

```
//test the global context variables
(function() {
    console.log(this.g_var_1);  //ok
    console.log(this.g_var_2);  //undefined
    console.log(g_var_1);       //ok
    console.log(g_var_2);       //ok
    this.g_func();              //Error
    g_func();                   //ok
})();
```

`this` will be undefined so none of the references from it will work.  The normally declared variables work as expected.

Comment: @user1726366 - I added a strict mode explanation.

Comment: @jriend00 Roger that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use 'var' before the name of the var you're declaring it's global. Then, If you want to redeclare that variable, for example, inside a function, you put 'var' before the name inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I put this picture together in order to better explain how the global scope is working in Node.js.

- when you run a *.js file ('main.js' in this case) you are NOT in the global scope, you're in the 'main' module, BUT in JavaScript if you declare an identifier without the keyword [var let const ] it becomes a global variable automatically!

`myVar        // same as global.myVar (in Node)
              // same as window.myVar (in the browser)`

- when you declare the [ g_var_1 ] it becomes global, you basically declared [ global.g_var_1 ]
- the [ this ] keyword refers to the current module (scope) not the global scope
- in the main.js we run the [ require('./module1.js') ] and [ require('./module2.js') ] methods, this basically tells Node that module1.js and module2.js modules share the same global scope
- if we would declare in module1.js [ mod1Var ] or [ global.mod1Var ] when we run the main.js file we can access to that data!
- Note that :

Node is not designed to declare variables in the global scope, this is just for better explain how it works (it's in its "Node.js" we use multiple nodes (modules) to avoid name conflicts and use awesome structuring)

You should avoid using identifiers without the keyword [var let const], in strict mode this is not allowed!

[image: Node.js Basic Structure]